# Modularizar apenas Views do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
- resources/
  - views
    - Modulo1
     - view01.blade.php
    - Modulo2
     - view01.blade.php
```

Porem estou com um problema, não consigo usar as diretivas do blade sem conflito, se eu uso dentro de modulo02/view01 chamando um outro arquivo que esta dentro do mesmo modulo ele me gera um erro pois não encontra o arquivo, eu tenho que passar o caminho completo para funcionar por exemplo:

```
  @include('Modulo02.pasta1.view2');
```

Porem queria que o blade entendesse qual pasta ele estava, tipo o contexto, para que eu não precisasse chamar o caminho completo isso é possível ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amigo, acredito que o que você procura é "namespaces" nas views.

Vou mostrar duas formas de se fazer (e provavelmente ainda existam outras maneiras).

**Opção 1**:

**app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->app['view']->addNamespace('admin', base_path() . '/resources/views/admin');
}
```

**route/web.php**

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('admin::index');
});
```

E tendo a seguinte estrutura de views:

```
resources/views/admin/index.blade.php
resources/views/admin/partials/hello.blade.php
```

**resources/views/admin/index.blade.php**

```
@include('admin::partials/hello')
```

**resources/views/admin/partials/hello.blade.php**

```
hello from admin
```

Ao acessar a url "*/admin*", o navegador deverá mostrar a mensagem "*hello from admin*".

**Opção 2**, adicionar dinamicamente o namespace:

**route/web.php**

```
Route::get('/modulo1', function () {
    app('view')->addNamespace('modulo', base_path() . '/resources/views/modulo1');
    return view('modulo::index');
});

Route::get('/modulo2', function () {
    app('view')->addNamespace('modulo', base_path() . '/resources/views/modulo2');
    return view('modulo::index');
});
```

E tendo a seguinte estrutura de views:

```
resources/views/modulo1/index.blade.php
resources/views/modulo1/partials/hello.blade.php
resources/views/modulo2/index.blade.php
resources/views/modulo2/partials/hello.blade.php
```

**resources/views/modulo1/index.blade.php**

```
@include('modulo::partials/hello')
```

**resources/views/modulo1/partials/hello.blade.php**

```
hello from modulo1
```

**resources/views/modulo2/index.blade.php**

```
@include('modulo::partials/hello')
```

**resources/views/modulo2/partials/hello.blade.php**

```
hello from modulo2
```

Ao acessar a url "*/modulo1*" e "*/modulo2*", o navegador deverá mostrar as respectivas mensagens "*hello from modulo1*" e "*hello from modulo2*".

Criei um repositório bem simples com os arquivos de teste: [exemplo-utilizando-vies-namespaces-laravel](https://github.com/paulosakamoto/exemplo-utilizando-vies-namespaces-laravel/)

O Laravel disponibiliza um hook que é disparado quando uma view é reinderizada: [Laravel: View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers)

Você pode utilizar essa view composer para setar dinamicamente o namespace por exemplo, é só questão de usar a criatividade.

Não testei mas, acredito que poderia ainda adicionar esses namespaces nas rotas, ou ainda através de middlewares. Já utilizei algo parecido uma vez, e no meu sistema eu criei um *ViewServiceProvider* e resolvi por lá. É questão de ver o que ficar melhor no seu sistema, usar a criatividade mesmo.

Espero que ajude.